# Application delegate received call to -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, pusher

Iam using pusher.com to send push notification from our server to our flutter apps, on android is normaly work but on ios is the problem receive Application delegate received call to -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called

but from print response my apps get the result from pusher.com
[image]

please help if anybody have similiar problem like me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to end your function with a `completionHandler`, otherwise the function will misbehave

```
func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void
) {


//

completionHandler(.newData) // or whatever you want

}
```

Comment: this is will work on flutter? i am use a flutter to develop ios not a native